# Ubuntu 18.04 - The following packages have been kept back

Tags: server

I updated my server from 16.04 to 18.04 a few days ago, today I found this:

```
19 packages can be updated.
18 updates are security updates.
```

I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-bcmath php7.2-bz2 php7.2-cgi php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-intl php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-zip
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php7.2 snap-confine snapd ubuntu-core-launcher
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 12.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-core-launcher amd64 2.32.8+18.04 [1,644 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.32.8+18.04 [12.2 MB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 snap-confine amd64 2.32.8+18.04 [1,792 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 php7.2 all 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [9,240 B]
Fetched 12.2 MB in 2s (6,527 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 81195 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-core-launcher_2.32.8+18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-core-launcher (2.32.8+18.04) over (2.32.5+18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.32.8+18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.32.8+18.04) over (2.32.5+18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../snap-confine_2.32.8+18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snap-confine (2.32.8+18.04) over (2.32.5+18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../php7.2_7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php7.2 (7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.32.8+18.04) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.seeded.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/cloud-final.service.wants/snapd.seeded.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up php7.2 (7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up ubuntu-core-launcher (2.32.8+18.04) ...
Setting up snap-confine (2.32.8+18.04) ...
```

Now:

```
18 packages can be updated.
17 updates are security updates.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-bcmath php7.2-bz2 php7.2-cgi php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-fpm php7.2-gd php7.2-intl php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-zip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
```

How is that possible? What did I miss?
Is a web server updated a few days ago, the update is about PHP which is very important for a web server.
What can I do? 
What should I do? 
Will they update later along with other updates?
Is this behavior normal after a few days from the version update?
My server is in Vultr, maybe something is missing in Vultr?

Comment: Duplicate of what? About that on StackOverflow? 
You told me that the post was on the wrong place, I deleted it from StackOverflow and rewritten on askubuntu. It's no good?

Answer (score 3):

My first question is, have you rebooted the system to ensure any previous updates (that require OS to be logged out) have been applied?

Second, have you tried this command?

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

In my experience, all updates will apply to a newly built system over a day or 2 but you can try to force it.

Comment: I did reboot. To update I followed this procedure: https://www.alebalweb-blog.com/67-aggiornare-ubuntu-server-a-18-04.html